# devise_token_auth update request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, httprequest

Hello I'm using the [`devise_auth_token`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem, and testing my server with postman with a PUT request to `/` following this indications :

> Account updates. This route will update an existing user's account
>   settings. The default accepted params are password and
>   `password_confirmation`, but this can be customized using the
>   `devise_parameter_sanitizer` system. If
>   `config.check_current_password_before_update` is set to `:attributes` the
>   `current_password` param is checked before any update, if it is set to
>   `:password` the `current_password` param is checked only if the request
>   updates user password.

I made this request ->

Header :

```
"access-token": "wwwww",
"token-type":   "Bearer",
"client":       "xxxxx",
"expiry":       "yyyyy",
"uid":          "zzzzz"
```

Body :

```
{  
  "name": "MI NOMBRE",
  "nickname": "MI APODO",
  "role": "MI ROL"
}
```

and i get this error :  `Please submit proper account update data in request body.`

This are my permited params in `application_controller.rb`:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :password_confirmation
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:role, :email, :nickname, :name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
```

My server message :

```
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#update as */*
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = ? LIMIT 1  [["uid", "test2@gmail.com"]]
Filter chain halted as :validate_account_update_params rendered or redirected
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 85ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: This error is related to rails Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection, not to devise. Have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) for more details, you have to add the CSRF token to all non-GET requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it says that all non-get requests must be added, that means that i have to get the token after each request the user does, and then sends it back on the next request made? where i can see an example of this? even better if it it's related to react.

Comment: If you are using react, most likely you are still using jquery_ujs, which takes care of CSRF for you. You are seeing the problem because you are contacting the API using postman, forms generated by your app should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In case your testing this on local machine you'll probably need to allow cross site requests first. Update your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rack-cors'
end
```

in `config/environments/development.rb` add following:

```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    # allow all origins in development
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*',
          :headers => :any,
          :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options],
          :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
          :max_age => 0
    end
  end
```

Then on client side there are multiple libraries you can use. All of them would store the `auth-token` on client (cookies, session store, ...) and then inject token into each request. Depending on your stack you can choose from:

- [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) for AngularJS
- [Angular2-Token](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token) for Angular2
- [jToker](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker) for jQuery

Basically the validation looks like this (image from `ng-token-auth`):

[image: ng-token-auth flow]

When client HTML was rendered on server (Rails) it was common practice to include CSRF tag somewhere in page layout:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

If you really want do do this with postman and let's say you have just JSON API, you can do set token in `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :set_token
def set_token
  response.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token
end
```

now when you send `GET /` you'll be able to retrieve

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN: Tjbsg1RYL6bBoCK1u1As8/SO09V+vZ+IOyfNrRXdyfNb9DeWjwnArv6IZkyr2+ayMchwywXPyausYOQhWNGK1g==
```

from response headers. And afterwards you have to use it for submitting `PUT` request. That's just to illustrate how this works, using some library for managing tokens is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for a solution, after setting up cross site requests using gem 'rack-cors'.

In `application_controller.rb` add following:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :password_confirmation])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :nickname, :image])
  end
```

Tested and works in Rails 5.2.1